# Visibility of faces of simple polytope from point

Tags: algorithm, graphics, 3d, polygon, computational-geometry

What algorithms of computational geometry related to the topic of visibility of faces in general? Or what name of the field of study of the determination of visible faces 3D objects?

Comment: The google words are "hidden surface removal"

Comment: @MattTimmermans , yeees, this what I need. Thank!

Comment: the easy start up is like this [Back face Culling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48784455/2521214)

Comment: The relevant term in computational geometry is *visibility (from a point), in 3D*.

Comment: @Spektre Thanks a lot