# How to get a list the visible vertices and segments of a mesh

Tags: python, opengl

I work on pose estimation of a 3d objects. I am using CAD model of that object to generate all the possible hypothesis of its pose. 
I am using pyopengl to render the view of the object from a specific POV. Can anyone explain how to get a list of all the visible edges?

So I use face culling to eliminate the occluded faces, but I don't know how to pass the visible edges(indices and segments) to other python functions.

If there are any other approaches (not using OpenGL), I would really appreciate it.

So I want to get the drawn edges in the The rendered image:

[image: img]

I don't really want the image to be displayed. 
In summary, I have a CAD model, and I want a function that can return the visible segments out of a specific POV.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: What do you mean by "which vertices are visible"? Just because all vertices of a triangle are invisible, that doesn't mean that the triangle is invisible.

Comment: Hi @BDL, Sorry for the vague description. I want a list of the visible edges of the object. So, I want to exclude the self-occluded edges.

Comment: then filter them out ... by checking `dot(face_normal,camera_direction)` if your mesh has strict winding rule ... that is how `GL_FACE_CULL` do it... but that works only for convex meshes of coarse for concave or multiple meshes you would need  other methods like Z-buffer .... you can render edge indices instead of color and than just scan the resulting image to create list of unique edges .... With self intersecting meshes its even worse and you need computational geometry

Comment: Hi @Spektre,
can you please explain how to do the dot as I am new to this field. I work with python but never before used OpenGL. So I dont know how to get the face_normal and the camera_direction

Comment: @AhmedAbbas added answer with some explanations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Face culling**

This works only for single convex strict winding rule mesh without holes!

The idea is that sign of dot product of 2 vectors will tell you if the vectors are opposite or not. So if we have a normal pointing out and view direction their dot should be negative for faces turned towards camera/viewer.

As you do not want to render just select visible planar faces/edges you can do this on **CPU** side entirely. What you need is to have your mesh in form of planar faces (does not matter if triangles,quads or whatever) so let assume triangles (for more points you just add them to `_face` but for computation still use only `v0,v1,v2`) ... Each face should have the vertexes and normal.

```cpp
struct _face
 {
 double v0[3],v1[3],v2[3],n[3];
 };

List<_face> mesh;
```

Now the vertexes `v0,v1,v2` you already have. All of them should be ordered in strict winding rule. That means if you look at any face from outside the points should form only **CW** (clockwise) loop (or only **CCW** (counter-clockwise) loop). To compute normal you simply exploit cross product which returns vector perpendicular to both operands:

```
n = cross(v1-v0,v2-v1) // cross product
n = n / |n|            // optional normalize to unit vector
```

If you need the vector math see

- [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

On the bottom is how to compute this... Also the whole answer you will need for the camera direction so read it...

Now if your mesh has strict winding rule than all the computed normals are pointing out of mesh (or inwards depends on your coordinate system, **CW/CCW** and order of operands in cross product). Let assume they all pointing out (if not just negate normal).

In case you do not have strict winding rule compute avg point of your mesh (sum all vertexes and divide by their count) this will be the center `c` of your object. Now just compute

```
dot(n,(v0+v1+v2)/3 - c)
```

and if not positive negate the `n`. This will repair your normals (you can also reverse the `v0,v1,v2` to repair the mesh.

Now the camera and mesh usually has its own 4x4 transform matrix. one transfroms from mesh **LCS** (local coordinate system) to **GCS** ("world" global coordinate system) and the other from **GCS** to camera **LCS** (screen). We do not need projections for this as we do not render ... So what we need to do for each face is:

1. convert `n` to **GCS**
2. compute `dot(n,camera_view_direction)`

   where `camera_view_direction` is **GCS** vector pointing in view direction. You can take it from direct camera matrix directly. It is usually the `Z` axis vector (in **OpenGL** Perspective view it is `-Z`). Beware camera matrix used for rendering is inverse matrix so if the case either compute inverse first or transpose it as we do not need the offset anyway ...
3. decide if face visible from the sign of **#2**

Again all the math is explained in the link above...

In case you do not have mesh matrix (does not have changing position or orientation) you can assume its matrix is unit one which means `GCS = mesh LCS` so no need for transformations.

In some cases there is no camera and only mesh matrix (I suspect your case) then it is similar you just ignore the camera transforms and use `(0,0,-1)` or `(0,0,+1)` as view direction.

Also see this:

- [Understanding lighting in OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29004546/2521214)

It should shine some light on the **normals** topic.